# How to identify which procedure used a table in oracle

Tags: oracle, list, stored-procedures

I have a code in sybase which I use to fetch the procedures that use a given table.

What would be the equivalent Oracle code

```
use <<database>>
go
select so.type,so.name from sysobjects so, syscomments sc
where so.id=sc.id
and sc.text like '%<<tablename>>%'
and so.type='U'
```

Comment: The table `all_objects` might be worth looking at

Comment: you may want to read about [ALL_DEPENDENCIES](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/server.111/b28320/statviews_1066.htm#i1576452) table

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
select owner, name, type, text
from all_source where text like lower('%<<tablename>>%');
```

`TYPE` is the oracle object type like `PACKAGE`,`PROCEDURE`,`FUNCTION`, etc.